I can't found file named pubspec.yaml on android studio?
on my android studio i can't see the name pubspec.yaml file is there ways the see the file?
any time i need edit something on that file i had to shortcut ctr+alt+n that make me sad so much. i been try in setting file type and it didn't help me. Please help thank you for time!

Just generate a new flutter project and copy everything there simple or just copy the pubspec.yaml file and import everything again.
